# 日本語に違和感: 「スタック・オーバーフロー は JavaScript が有効になっている場合に最もよく動作する」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

原文が`Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled` なので翻訳としては何も間違ってないのですが、自然な日本語ではない気がします。
「スタック・オーバーフローをより快適に使うためにはJavaScriptを有効化してください」くらいのほうが耳触りもよく自然ではないでしょうか。

Comment: Transifex: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「スタック・オーバーフローをより快適に使うためにはJavaScriptを有効化してください」に更新しました。

次回のビルドに適用されます。